# How does Unity distinguish between Android and iOS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Let's say we have make a mobile game based on accelerometer. We're using Input.accelerometer class.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 10.0F;
    void Update() {
        Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;
        dir.x = -Input.acceleration.y;
        dir.z = Input.acceleration.x;
        if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
            dir.Normalize();

        dir *= Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(dir * speed);
    }
}
```

This code works on Andoid and on iOS. Im wondering, how does Unity know if we're running the game on Android or iOS? I have checked UnityEngine.dll file and I did not find any if-else statement between the operating systems.

Comment: This may be a shot in the dark, but when your running on Windows you are using the UnityEngine.dll...  however I don't believe Android or iOS use the dll... I believe they use .so's or .a's  why would you find anything in the UnityEngine.dll for distinguishing the 2 different OS's?

Comment: Also, I believe most developers would use a preprocess command to prevent unnecessary code from being compiled thiings like #if #elif #else.  If you are compiling a .so or even a .dll and your #if condition isn't true, then the code in that body wouldn't be included with the finished object.

Comment: The target platform is decided at *build time*, you won't find anything in the library files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There basically two sides of Unity which are the managed and native side. The managed part is just the C# API and the native side is just the native side of the code written in C++ that communicates with Object-C Swift for iOS or Java for Android to access.

The managed part extension is usually *.dll* and the native side for Android are usually *.so*, *.aar*, *.jar* or just a *.dex*.

The managed part extension for iOS native side are usually *.a*, *.m*, *.mm*, *.c*, *.cpp*. For iOS, some manage part are not compiled and still in form of *.cpp* until you build the generated project with xCode.

> This code works on Andoid and on iOS. Im wondering, how does Unity
>   know if we're running the game on Android or iOS?

They don't do this during run-time. There are so many Unity API and doing this every time would be redundant and messy.

**To simplify this, it uses different managed and native files for different platforms.** These files are included during build-time and this decision is made in the Editor once you click the build button.

First, go to `<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines`

[image]

To avoid using some [preprocessor directives](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html), [`Application.platform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-platform.html) or mising different platforms codes, this is done in the Editor during build time. If you select iOS and build the project, it will include `UnityEngine.dll` for iOS located in the C:\Program `<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\iOSSupport` path. It will do the-same for Android but in the `<UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer` path.

There are different *UnityEngine.dll* for each platform. You can see them in the path I mentioned above. This *UnityEngine.dll* and other managed dlls is where you will see a call to the native side of the code with `DllImport` or with `AndroidJavaClass`. Note that *UnityEngine.dll* is not the only file included in that build. Most files in these paths, with the extensions I mentioned above are included. These includes the managed and native files.

Comment: Is there any way I can see where and how we get the data from the Android sensor? Im assuming Unity's class "Input.acceleration" gets data out of Android's class "public static final int TYPE_ACCELEROMETER" (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor#TYPE_ACCELEROMETER). Is this class included anywhere in the <UnityInstallationDirecory>\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer path?

Comment: Yes it is but it is not open source. You can't see the source unless you decompile it which is against Unity's terms you agreed. If you work for a company, you can pay Unity to get the source code but it's very expensive.The file is there. For accelerometer, I suspect one of the ".so" or ".a files. For the Input.GetKeyXX functions then it's in the "classes.jar" file at `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\mono\Release\Classes` if you de-compile the jar file. You will see the implementation there.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to determine what platform you are on would be to check with the `#define` directives that Unity uses. You can find more information about it in [the docs here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

Here is an example of how you can check if you are on Android or IOS:

```
#if UNITY_ANRDOID
     // Android code goes here
#elif UNITY_IOS
     // IOS Code goes here
#endif
```

Hope this helps!

If you want a runtime check, then you can use the [RuntimePLatform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer.html)

```
if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
     value = 5;
 else if(Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
    value = 10;
```

Comment: Question is not asking "how to determine the platform.". I think you should read it again

Comment: Edited to add a runtime check as well, although the question does ask : Im wondering, how does Unity know if we're running the game on Android or iOS?

Comment: When you said *"The proper way to determine what platform you are on would be to check with the #define directives that Unity uses."* it seems more like you were telling OP how to detect platform instead of answering how unity detects which platform it is to use a different API.  The question is asking how one API works on multiple platforms. How Unity determines which API to use on each platform.

Comment: @Programmer It's quite obvious this is the answer the OP was asking for.